# Unable to install opencv on 12.04

Tags: software-installation, opencv

I want to OpenCV it for image processing in a line tracer robot using camera. I want to install openCV on my 64-bit laptop with ubuntu 12.04 2GB Nvidia card.

I tried the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libopen-dev
```

but I am getting errors like unable to correct and you have some broken packages:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv-dev : Depends: libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-calib3d-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-features2d-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-legacy-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-contrib-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libopencv-dev
```