# Dependency problems with wkhtmltopdf when trying to install latest version

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

I'm trying to install the latest version of wkhtmltopdf on an ubuntu server 12.04. apt-get install wkhtmltopdf only installs version 0.9.9 and I need the latest version, 0.12.2.1. I was having trouble so I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390940/how-to-install-the-latest-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu-12-04), but that didn't work, and seemed to cause more problems as I was trying things I don't understand.

I found a way to install the latest version. That is, download the latest version and install it like this `dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-precise-i386.deb`

Although when I try do that now, I get this

```
Selecting previously unselected package wkhtmltox:i386.
(Reading database ... 178460 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking wkhtmltox:i386 (from .../wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-precise-i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:i386:
wkhtmltox:i386 depends on xfonts-base.
wkhtmltox:i386 depends on xfonts-75dpi.
wkhtmltox:i386 depends on libstdc++6.
dpkg: error processing wkhtmltox:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
wkhtmltox:i386
```

And when I try and do `sudo dpkg -a --configure` it gives me this

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:i386:
 wkhtmltox:i386 depends on xfonts-base.
 wkhtmltox:i386 depends on xfonts-75dpi.
 wkhtmltox:i386 depends on libstdc++6.
dpkg: error processing wkhtmltox:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wkhtmltox:i386
```

How can I fix these dependency problems?

Comment: try to do like here http://askubuntu.com/questions/603672/unable-to-install-opencv-on-12-04/603678#603678 except installing opencv

Comment: Yeah, I saw this. I'm a little nervous to 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' as I don't want it to affect any of the sites running on the server. I've tried up to that point though.

Comment: well if you need that package to be installed you need to proceed with `dist-upgrade` as it requires certain libs or you install those packages manually then.

Comment: Nevermind the previous comment. Naïvety on my part in not understanding the command fully. Will try it now.

Comment: I did the `dist-upgrade` and still getting the same problems. When I do the apt-get -f install it says it needs to remove this package wkhtmltox:i386 and then fails with this:
 
`Removing wkhtmltox:i386 ...

dpkg: warning: while removing wkhtmltox:i386, directory 
'/usr/local/share' not empty so not removed.

dpkg: warning: while removing wkhtmltox:i386, directory '/usr/local/bin' not empty so not removed.

dpkg: warning: while removing wkhtmltox:i386, directory '/usr/local/lib' not empty so not removed.`

Comment: did you try manually to remove it `sudo apt-get remove --purge wkhtmltox:i386`

Comment: It gives the same problem. It won't remove it because '/usr/local/share', '/usr/local/bin' and '/usr/local/lib' are not empty.  I don't know why it's giving these problems. Those folders seem important so I don't know why it wants to delete them anyways.

Comment: read this thread http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164321/after-creating-a-deb-dpkgwarning-while-removing-directory-usr-local-bin-not you have to understand more clearly. One thing might also happen when you installed packages as a root also so might need to login as root to un-do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, I ran into this same problem and it turned out to be an issue with the version of wkhtmltopdf I was trying to install. I have an Ubuntu 12.04.5 64-bit system and was trying to install a 32-bit version of the package. Looks like you have the 32-bit version there as well; should it be amd64 instead of i386? All package downloads here: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I finally managed to sort it out. And this was exactly the problem. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 21):

on Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

(correct architecture 32 bit)

```
$ dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-i386.deb 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:
wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-base; however:
  Package xfonts-base is not installed.
wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-75dpi; however:
 Package xfonts-75dpi is not installed.
```

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS:

```
 sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb 
 Selecting previously unselected package wkhtmltox.
 (Reading database ... 230695 files and directories currently 
installed.)
 Preparing to unpack wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking wkhtmltox (1:0.12.6-1.focal) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-75dpi; however:
 Package xfonts-75dpi is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wkhtmltox (--install):
dependency problems - leaving configured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

Now just issue the following command:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Comment: As sudo, downloaded .deb from downloads page, then ran `apt-get -f install`. It installed all dependencies. Worked like a charm.